# Sort keyword field array within ElasticSearch document by relevance

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an ElasticSearch index that looks something like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "article": {
            "properties": {
                "title": { "type": "string" },
                "tags": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
        }
    }
}
```

And data that looks something like this:

```
{ "title": "Something about Dogs", "tags": ["articles", "dogs"] },
{ "title": "Something about Cats", "tags": ["articles", "cats"] },
{ "title": "Something about Dog Food", "tags": ["articles", "dogs", "dogfood"] }
```

If I search for `dog`, I get the first and third documents, as I'd expect. And I can weight the search documents the way I like (in reality, I'm using a `function_score` query to weight on a bunch of fields irrelevant to this question).

What I'd *like* to do is sort the `tags` field so that the most relevant tags are returned first, *without affecting the sort order of the documents themselves*. So I'm hoping for a result like this:

```
{ "title": "Something about Dog Food", "tags": ["dogs", "dogfood", "articles"] }
```

Instead of what I get now:

```
{ "title": "Something about Dog Food", "tags": ["articles", "dogs", "dogfood"] }
```

The documentation on [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-sort.html) and [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) don't cover my case. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of ES is this, since you are using `"type":"string"`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Using 5.5.0

Comment: You should consider moving to `text`/'keyword' fields. `string`s are [deprecated in 5.x and removed in 6.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16877).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot sort the `_source` (your array of tags) of the documents given its "matching" capability. One way of doing this is by using nested fields and `inner_hits` that allows you to sort the matching nested fields.

My suggestion is to transform your `tags` in a `nested` field (I chose `keyword` there just by simplicity, but you can also have `text` and the analyzer of your choice):

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "article": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use this kind of query:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "exclude": "tags"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "dogs"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "tags.value": "dogs"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "sort": {
                "_score": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Where you try to match on the tags nested field value for the same text you try to match on title. Then, using `inner_hits` sorting, you can actually sort the nested values based on their inner scoring.

@Val's suggestion is very good, but is good as long as for your "relevant tags" you are ok with just a simple text matching as a substring (`i1.indexOf(params.search)`). His solution's biggest advantage is that you don't have to change the mapping.

My solution's big advantage is that you are actually using Elasticsearch true search capabilities to determine the "relevant" tags. But the drawback is that you need `nested` field instead of the regular simple `keyword`.

Comment: Great job as usual Andrei, I was thinking of providing an update with `inner_hits` sorting, but glad you did it ;-)

Comment: This seems like a really good approach. Is the performance of this analogous to a SQL subquery?

Comment: There are many variables in this evaluation. Even though I don't particularly like it, the best performance evaluation you can get is by testing both approaches. A nested query is heavier than the usual query,  but probably not by much. A scripted query is also a bit heavier than the usual simple query, but I cannot tell you by how much. Depending on your requirements and your app response times, you can be very well with either nested documents or scripted fields. My suggestion is to test this and, as much as possible, on real load and real set of data.

Answer (score 2):

What you get from a search call are the source documents. The documents in the response are returned in exactly the same form as when you indexed them, which means that if you indexed `["articles", "dogs", "dogfood"]`, you'll always get that array in that unaltered form.

One way to get around this is to declare a [`script_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) that applies a small script to sort your array and return the result of that sort.

What the script does is simply move the terms that contain the search term in the front of the list

```
{
    "_source": ["title"],
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "sorted_tags" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "return params._source.tags.stream().sorted((i1, i2) -> i1.indexOf(params.search) > -1 ? -1 : 1).collect(Collectors.toList())",
                "params" : {
                    "search": "dog"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return something like this, as you can see the `sorted_tags` array contains the terms as you expect.

```
{
  "took": 18,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "tests",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Something about Dog Food"
        },
        "fields": {
          "sorted_tags": [
            "dogfood",
            "dogs",
            "articles"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```